# Exception occurs only in debug mode

Tags: c++, exception, debugging

I'm developing a C++ project by Visual Studio 2015 Pro update 2.

My sample code is as below:

MyClass.h

```
class MyClass
{
    vector<int> vectorBig;
    ...
    Constructor declare
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
MyClass::MyClass(),
vectorBig(0)
{
}

void TestMethod()
{
     int a = *max_element(vectorBig.begin(), vectorBig.end());
}
```

When I run my application, an exception occurs at max_element process.
However, it only occurs in Debug mode and not in Release mode.

I dont know why.
Please help me.

Thanks

I can know why exception only occurs in Debug mod

Comment: Because `std::max_element` returns `vectorBig.end()` if the vector is empty. and dereferencing the `end` iterator is *undefined behavior*

Comment: Visual Studio enables checked iterators in debug builds, which can help catch errors like this. That's probably why you're getting an exception.

Comment: Side note : stop using `using namespace std;` too. See this [C++ weekly episode on stop using `using namespace std;`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZqjl9HEPZ8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to elaborate on what other comments mentioned.
Debug vs Release - `debug` mode is meant to help us (devlopers) find bugs in our program. Variables are not optimized out, bounds are checked, classes are not inlined, debug asserts are evaluted, etc. Things that would make our lives as developers easier. Including one important feature - iterator validation. If you dereference the iterator you get from calling `end()` you received from a standard library container, it would throw an exception and crash your program. That will help you find bugs because you are never allowed to do it and your program will always crash if you do it, so you can find where you've made a mistake and how.
But it comes with a cost - everything is slower. Much slower.
`release` versions are versions that will reach production and customer environments. Those need to be as fast as possible. So all these extra checks get thrown out the window. In the case of iterators, instead of an exception being thrown when you dereference an `end()` iterator, the program's behavior is undefined. Something will happen. Maybe it is what you meant, maybe it isn't. It might crash because you tried to read memory you are not allowed to (in that case, it is the operating system that kills your program), maybe it will bring in some garbage data.

Now, for the problem at hand. Like mentioned by others, if the input to `max_element` is an empty vector, it will return the result of a call to `end()` on the input vector.
Dereferencing that is undefined behavior.
In debug, you get training wheels and an exception is thrown. In release, you get undefined behavior.
I encourage you to read about both `max_element` and `std::vector::end` in `cppreference`, it is a great website.